# Can't reproduce example of Stepper from Material-UI properly

Tags: material-ui

I can't reproduce example of Stepper from Material-UI properly. When I copy the source code from [Vertical Linear Stepper](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/stepper) within Material-UI the heigth of the Stepper takes all available heigth but not 400px as specified in the style of the element. See please a screenshot. 
[Heigth stretches to body value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIT4l.png)

I thoroughly compared generated styles each by each with the example but failed figure out the difference.

Where should I investigate further or what I.m doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: did u get the solution or still facing the problem ??

Comment: Hey, I just checked this code with `Strorybook boilerplate` [project](https://github.com/sm-react/react-theming#storybook-boilerplate-project) and everything works properly. So maybe it worth to create it from scratch?

Comment: No, I failed to figure out the reason so I have implemented my own stepper.